# Adding a custom "ALL" (Total) row to the top of an ag-grid that is selectable like any other row

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have an ag-grid table with 2 columns - one text and one number.

I need to add a custom row to the top of my ag-grid table with the total value of the number column and the word "ALL" in the text column.

This needs to be on the top. And should not change its position even if the table is sorted.

Also, the row should be selectable.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are describing [Row Pinning](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/row-pinning/) which is already a feature in AG Grid. However, since you've also stated that row selection is a requirement, this will not be possible with Row Pinning as it's [not supported](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/row-pinning/#non-supported-items).

Instead what I'd recommend is adding an extra row object inside the `rowData` for the custom row, and handling the update of the number column and the custom row position yourself when necessary:

If you want to handle the total value of the number column then you can use the following logic:

```
function updateTotalRowNode() {
  let totalRowNode;
  let sum = 0;
  gridOptions.api.forEachNode((node) => {
    if (node.data.totalRow) {
      totalRowNode = node;
    } else {
      sum += node.data.gold;
    }
  });
  totalRowNode.setDataValue('gold', sum);
}
```

If you want to keep the custom row always on the top row then you can [implement the `postSort` callback](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/row-sorting/#post-sort):

```
  postSort: (rowNodes) => {
    // here we put All row on top while preserving the sort order
    let nextInsertPos = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < rowNodes.length; i++) {
      const athlete = rowNodes[i].data.athlete;
      if (athlete === 'All') {
        rowNodes.splice(nextInsertPos, 0, rowNodes.splice(i, 1)[0]);
        nextInsertPos++;
      }
    }
  },
```

See the [following plunker for the implementation](https://plnkr.co/edit/e2gjQl3J83NVnhL0).

Comment: Hi Shuheb - This piece of code is not working at my end. Do I need to do something to refresh the grid ? 

Somethings to note... 
 - I am using React JS using TypeScript
 - I am not using gridOptions - rather, all the properties are set along with the component.. like    <rowData={xxx},onSortChanged={sortChanged}, etc... 
 - in your sortChanged function, you have rowNodes as a parameter... where are you sending it ? In my case... putting rowNodes is throwing an error.... 

(counted in next...)

Comment: (contd from previous...)

so, I have declared rowNodes inside the sortChanged function like this
   const rowNodes = gridApi?.getRenderedNodes()

Then I do a console.log with the nextInsertPos and I values and when it gets the "All" row the values printed are correct... 

However, the table does not update....

Comment: Hi, I'm not using sortChanged in the example, I'm using postSort which is a grid callback. This callback has rowNodes as a parameter. So you will have to define it like this:

< postSort={postSort} , etc... />

Comment: Oh! apologies. Ok, in my component I have postSort={postSort}.... but then outside when I write the postSort function, I am writing like this....... const postSort = (rowNodes} => { //function }....... so, in this I am getting an error in the (rowNodes) part.... parameter rowNodes implicitly has an any type....

Comment: so putting (rowNodes: any} solved it.... but is it a good practice to use "any" ?

Comment: If you're using typescript then it's up to you how you want to handle type safety issues. In any case, have a look at the gridOption type definitions for ag-grid: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/e2fe514849df35e9e88dfe779d86f7a42351e855/community-modules/core/src/ts/entities/gridOptions.ts#L458

As you can see, postSort is defined as follows:

postSort?(nodes: RowNode[]): void;